# How to compare every element of two lists with every other one and then combine the results in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I use Python 3.7.3 .

I have two lists of integers, a and b, now I want to save values in a string, which are the result of a smaller-or-larger comparison between every element and every other element. I want to do that with both lists, and then combine the results. For example:

WARNING: IT'S GONNA GET COMPLICATED...

```
a = [1, 9, 4, 5]

b = [89, 43, 10, 0]
```

after a certain operation, which I don't know, there has been a string created from a and b (the following is only an example of what the result could look like, the values don't suit the above shown lists):

```
x = "0 - 1:l,h + 2:h,l + 3:l,h  ~  1 - 0:l,h + 2:h,l + 3:l,h  ~  2 - 0:l,h + 1:h,l + 3:l,h  ~  3 - 0:l,h + 1:h,l + 2:l,h"
```

The first number in the string x and the other numbers after the "~" represent the index of the element, which is afterwards (until the next "~") having the comparison values with every other element, shown. Let's just call the elements (plural, because it points to the index of two lists, with the same amount of elements) that the index points to "current element".

The number after the minus (the spaces in between are not important, they can be left out), represents the index of the element with which the current element is compared with. The two characters after the ":", which are separated with a comma, show if the current element of both a and b (the character before the comma represents the current element in a, and the character after the comma represents the current element in b) is smaller or larger than the element with which the current element is compared with. "l" stands for "the current element is larger than the element that it's being compared to", and h (I'm not so sure why I chose "h") stands for "the current element is smaller than the element that it's being compared to". Remember that the two lists don't have any operations happening between them, only inside of themselves. The plus signs between the comparison values are only there to separate them. After the "~", the cycle repeats, but with the current element shifting one index forward (until there are no element left to shift forward to). It's important, that in the string, the comparison values are sorted, so that it's like counting from the first to the last index, always leaving the current element out (because, obviously, comparing an element with oneself is useless, and the whole string would be useless it wasn't sorted like that) (f.e. if the current element has the index 2:  "2 - 0:l,h + 1:h,l + 3:l,h").

Also: I forgot to mention, that if the current element and the one that it's compared with (or "compared to", English is not my native language) are the same size, instead of putting an "l" or an "h" in, an "s" should be put in.

My python skills are not advanced enough to find a way to create a string with the above mentioned data. Can anyone show me how to get such a string out of two lists of integers?

Basically, I want to extract the most information possible out of two lists, for an AI-project, and then put it in a string, so that a certain function in my program can easily iterate through it and extract the information.

Comment: Though overall the rules are a bit "complicated", I don't see anything too difficult here. Looks like you just need to break the problem down into smaller pieces that are easier to tackle separately.

Comment: Believe me, I tried that so many times, but it never worked.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is there a specific reason you need to put the results of your processing into this exact, specific, (seemingly, to me) ad-hoc string encoding? It would be helpful if you explained exactly what the information is that you wish to extract in the first place, without worrying for now about how you would represent it, and that isn't entirely clear from your description either.

Comment: It sure would be helpful if this wasn't the case: `the values don't suit the above shown lists` Why not post an example with the correct output for the given input so we can check our understanding of your description against the example?

Comment: For example your `x` above could be represented much more clearly in a native Python data structure. There are many possible approaches but one might simply be a list of lists of tuples like `[[(-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1)], [(-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1)], [(-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1)], [(-1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, 1)]]` Instead of confusing character codes I used `-1`, `0` and `1` which are what you would get by `(a > b) - (b > a)` or equivalently `cmp(a, b)` in py2. Regardless, if you can build that data structure than converting it to your special string format is easy.

Comment: (of course, in the above data structure the permutation structure is implicit and would have to be documented; you can also use something like nested dicts to make the permutation structure more explicit).

Comment: Just to demonstrate the power of choosing a good data structure, here is a one-liner (albeit long and confusing; not recommended) that would generate your string format from the above data structure in a variable named `x`: `' ~ '.join('{} - {}'.format(i, ' + '.join('{}:{}'.format(jj, ','.join(('s', 'l', 'h')[c] for c in inner[j])) for j, jj in enumerate(jj for jj in range(len(x)) if jj != i))) for i, inner in enumerate(x))`

Comment: @Iguananaut For the operations that I want do on the string, it needs to look like that. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What operations though? Is it your own code or something that someone else came up with?

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood your question, but here's my take on it.

If you want to take as an input two lists, compare them such that, only the greater than/ less than values 'survive', for example:

```
a = [1, 9 ,4, 5]

b = [89, 43, 10, 0]

result_list = [9, 5, 89, 10]

result_string = 958910

result_sum = 113
```

Then the following code (Disclaimer: I'm a beginner in Python) might be suitable:

```
    # Question by John Plattenborough

    a = [1, 9, 4, 5]
    b = [89, 43, 10, 0]


    def convert_to_string(list):
        result = "".join(map(str, list))
        return result


    def sum_of_list(list):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(len(list)):
            sum += list[i]
        return sum


    def greatest_values(list_1, list_2):
        """
        :param list_1: A list of integers
        :param list_2: A list of integers
        :return: A list that contains the greatest values out of every two pairs in both of the lists
        """
        result = []
        for i in range(0, len(list_1), 2):
            if list_1[i] > list_1[i + 1]:
                result.append(list_1[i])
            elif list_1[i] < list_1[i + 1]:
                result.append(list_1[i + 1])
            else:
                # If they're equal
                result.append(list_1[i])
        for i in range(0, len(list_2), 2):
            if list_2[i] > list_2[i + 1]:
                result.append(list_2[i])
            elif list_2[i] < list_2[i + 1]:
                result.append(list_2[i + 1])
            else:
                # If they're equal
                result.append(list_2[i])
        return result


    result_list = greatest_values(a, b)
    result_string = convert_to_string(result_list)
    result_sum = sum_of_list(result_list)
    print(result_list)  # [9, 5, 89, 10]

    print(result_string)  # 958910

    print(result_sum)  # 113
```

If I didn't fully comprehend your question, John please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, dude. it's not what I'm looking for, but there is some helpful information in your post. I'm sure, that if I expressed myself a bit better, you would've found the answer! (Not to discriminate, I'm sure you put a lot of effort into that)

Comment: Maybe provide us a before and after states of the lists and the result you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can break this into a couple smaller steps to make it managable. You could start with a simple function that produces the comparison string:

```
def comp_str(orig, idx, n1, n2):
    strings = ['h', 'l']
    comps = ",".join(strings[orig < n] for n in [n1, n2])
    return f'{idx}:{comps}'

comp_str(10, 1, 9, 11)
# returns individual component:
# '1:h,l'
```

Then you can wrap this function in a list comprehension (or a couple if you want to break it down further)

```
comps = [f'{i} - ' + " + ".join([comp_str(n, x, a,b) 
                for x, (a,b) in enumerate(zip(a,b)) if x != i ]) 
                for i, n in enumerate(a)]
```

Given `a = [1, 9, 4, 5]` and `b = [89, 43, 10, 0]` this produces a list of the comparisons:

```
['0 - 1:l,l + 2:l,l + 3:l,h',
 '1 - 0:h,l + 2:h,l + 3:h,h',
 '2 - 0:h,l + 1:l,l + 3:l,h',
 '3 - 0:h,l + 1:l,l + 2:h,l']
```

Now you can just join those with the `~` separator:

```
' ~ '.join(comps)
```

Which results in a single string:

```
'0 - 1:l,l + 2:l,l + 3:l,h ~ 1 - 0:h,l + 2:h,l + 3:h,h ~ 2 - 0:h,l + 1:l,l + 3:l,h ~ 3 - 0:h,l + 1:l,l + 2:h,l'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, dude!

Comment: Hope it helps @JohnPlattenborough